# Error while installing SQL Server 2017 Express showing sqlncli.msi is missing in some path

Tags: sql-server-2017-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2017 Express, but it is throwing this error:

> sqlncli.msi is not found in the path

Screenshot illustrating the sqlncli.msi error:
[image: screenshot illustrating the sqlncli.msi error]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Sry.. link for image is posten.. plz check

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue, if you click cancel the next error should say something about a package from SQL Server 2012 Native Client is missing.

I then tried to install the sqlncli from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402 and it said I already have a new version. I had to unistall "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client" on add or remove programs, and install the sqlncli again from the website I mention and it all worked out.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem.
My solution, I uninstalled `SQL Server 2012 Native Client` and reinstall the SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The first two answers are more helpful and straight forward. Another way of installing *sqlncli.msi* is installing [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP4 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56041). It contains many packages including *sqlncli.msi*, which adds an additional value to your SQL server.

If you download only the native client as per @fpp.jesus's answer and if you want to install it using the command-line for some reason, the following command will be helpful.

```
msiexec /i sqlncli.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL APPGUID={0CC618CE-F36A-415E-84B4-FB1BFF6967E1}
```

*'ADDLOCAL=All*' argument will install SDK components along with the client components.